# What is static content in relation to web server?

Tags: javascript, nginx, dynamic, static

Nginx is declared as a considerably faster server than Apache in serving **static content**.

Is JavaScript code static or dynamic content?

Comment: static is if you have no "server langage" creating some lines in your pages like php, ruby, python, jee, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Static" means that the data is exactly the same for each and every request, which is opposed to "dynamic" responses which are generated individually for each request by a *server side program* (e.g. PHP, Python, Ruby, C#, any CGI script etc.). In other words, anything that just sits on disk as a file and is served as is is static data; anything that invokes a server side program is not.

Yes, Javascript files are static data as far as the web server is concerned, since the web server is just serving the Javascript file as is, it doesn't interpret or run it*.

<sub>* Unless it does, of course, via node.js or such.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

**Static** content is plain files like html, images, css, js

Pure javascript code files are considered static content when the bytes are served directly from the server without any modification (like templating/transpiling/generation).

Static resources can usually be cached.

**Dynamic** means the bytes are generated/modified by the server and thus not simply served as-is. Usually dynamic content is html server-side templates, generated image graphs and such.

NOTE: **it has nothing to do** with javascript being a [dynamic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language)

NOTE: any dynamic changes occuring inside the browser are not considered

Comment: JavaScript is text too until it is interpreted by browser as  JS

Comment: @alx I clarified a bit, because JS is also called a dynamic/interpreted language

Answer (score 1):

**Static Content**

Static content is published to regular files e.g. images, JavaScript, CSS on your server and handled using the simplest methods available to the web server.The content remains the same for every request.

The advantages of static content are:

- it is the fastest and most efficient way to deliver content
- it does not require any code to execute or any databases to be
  accessed, which  makes it the most secure way to deliver content
- it uses simple, clean URLs to address the content
- it takes best advantage of web caching systems, which further boosts
  performance
- it is compatible with every type of webserver technology

  However, it also has the following disadvantages:
- it must be republished when it changes, or your viewers will not see
  the updates
- it cannot display differently to different viewers, depending on
  their login status or other factors

**Dynamic Content**

Dynamic content is generated for you at the time you request the page.  The document you view exists only for you at that moment;  if viewed by someone else at the same time, or by you at a slightly different time, you could get something different.
Dynamic content is good for:

- pages whose content changes too quickly to easily republish it
- pages that display viewer-specific content (eg. user profiles)
- pages that display content conditionally (ie. member-only pages)

However, dynamic content has the following disadvantages:

- it is resource-intensive compared to static pages.  That means the
  number of dynamic pages your server can display per second will
  generally be much less than the number of static pages.  This can be
  especially important if you are swamped with traffic, or generating
  thousands of dynamic page views for robots or other automated agents
  that you don't really care about.
- dynamic pages execute code on your server, and can read from and write to your database.  If your website has any security problems, dynamic pages is where those problems will be exposed.
- in many typical default webserving configurations, the index page of a website is presumed to be a static page (eg. "index.html").  That means there are some places where it is impractical or more difficult to use dynamic pages than others.

Is JavaScript code static or dynamic content?

Yes the Javascript files residing on the server are considered to be static.